# Is the javascript .map() function supported in IE8?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, dictionary

When doing this:

```
var a = new Array("a", "b");
a.map(function() { });
```

in IE8 I get:

```
"Object doesn't support this property or method"
```

Is this method not supported in IE8, or do I have some other problem? I've had a Google, but get lots of Google Maps javascript issues/questions...

**Edit**: OK so IE8 and below DO NOT support the .map() function. Copy-paste the code from MDN [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Polyfill) which will add the .map() function to the Array prototype exactly per the specs if not natively supported (and it seems to work perfectly).

Answer (score 40, accepted):

IE8 doesn't support `map()`. When in doubt, check MDN (Mozilla Developer Network):

[map - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Browser_compatibility)

Looks like IE added support for `map()` in version 9.

Comment: I have found the compatibility script also useful.

Comment: Well is there any alternative for `map()` ? The most of my website's users use IE8 .. And I have used `map()` in my code, what should I do now? *(Note: I use jquery)*

Comment: @Shafizadeh - If you visit the link that I posted, you'll see that MDN provides a Polyfill that will allow you to use the `map` method in IE8.

Answer (score 45):

The solution is jQuery.map

Instead of this:
`a.map(function( ) { });`

You have to do

`jQuery.map(a, function( ) {
//what ever you want todo ..
}`

Comment: Perfect, can't believe I missed this. You're the man, thank you! This also should be the *accepted answer*. The one above is useless.

Comment: It's useful but shouldn't be the accepted answer as others are saying. No one said the OP was using jQuery and jQuery is not the answer to everything.

Comment: apologies to the author, but i am going to downvote this because "jQuery magically fixes everything" has become a mantra I see a lot and I'm rather sick of people relying on it for everything.. learn JavaScript, not jQuery! [Justin](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7350935/141881) has provided the MDN link in his answer and the polyfill on there works perfectly well without depending on a weighty third-party library.

Answer (score 22):

```
(function(fn){
    if (!fn.map) fn.map=function(f){var r=[];for(var i=0;i<this.length;i++)r.push(f(this[i]));return r}
    if (!fn.filter) fn.filter=function(f){var r=[];for(var i=0;i<this.length;i++)if(f(this[i]))r.push(this[i]);return r}
})(Array.prototype);
```

Put anywhere before first .map or .filter call. Problem solved. jQuery.map() method doesn't work as expected.

**UPDATE:**
I've just tested it on sparse arrays: if map or filter argument is a function which accepts and handles `undefined` value - it works, but the results are not obvious:

Let's define test sparse array:

```
var t = []
t[1] = 1; t[3] = 3; t[5] = 5;
```

Let's see what does IE8 say about t: **"[undefined, 1, undefined, 3, undefined, 5]"**

Let's try:

```
t.filter(function(x){return x<4})
```

What is it, IE8? It's: **"[1, 3]"**. Note - no undefined values. I would personally expect that.

But try THIS:

```
t.map(function(x){return 2<<x})
```

And... **"[2, 4, 2, 16, 2, 64]"**. That's weird! :) Try this:

```
t.map(function(x){return Math.pow(2,x)})
```

And?... **"[NaN, 2, NaN, 8, NaN, 32]"** - I would rather expect this result for the previous test. It's at least logical - Math.pow() is supposed to return a `number` type, `NaN`, regardless of it's meaning IS a special `number` type reserved for invalid operations. So the result is more or less correct. It would be fully correct as `map` result if t remained a sparse array.

So without further ado - **ultimately correct version of `map` and `filter` methods**:

```
(function(fn){
    if (!fn.map) fn.map=function(f){var r=[];for(var i=0;i<this.length;i++)if(this[i]!==undefined)r[i]=f(this[i]);return r}
    if (!fn.filter) fn.filter=function(f){var r=[];for(var i=0;i<this.length;i++)if(this[i]!==undefined&&f(this[i]))r[i]=this[i];return r}
})(Array.prototype);
```

And the test:

```
var t = []; t[1] = 1; t[3] = 3; t[5] = 5;
var t1 = t.map(function(x){return 2<<x});
var t2 = t.filter(function(x){return x<10});
console.debug(t);
console.debug(t1);
console.debug(t2);
```

Expected results:

> [object Array] [undefined, 1, undefined, 3, undefined, 5]
>
> [object Array][undefined, 4, undefined, 16, undefined, 64]
>
> [object Array][undefined, 1, undefined, 3, undefined, 5]

Comment: Love it. Even better solution!

Comment: What would be polyfill for reduce?

Answer (score 7):

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) says that IE 9 supports it. No mention of IE 8.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[On MSDN it is said in Requirements for map:
Not supported in the following document modes: Quirks, Internet Explorer 6 standards, Internet Explorer 7 standards, Internet Explorer 8 standards.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ff679976%28v=vs.94%29.aspx)

Map is just a implementation of "Visitor" pattern for array. So easy substitute for it could be:

```
function visitArray(arr, visitor) {
    var result = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i ++) {
        result[i] = visitor(arr[i]);
    }

    return result;
}
```

The function also takes array and function which to invoke on each array element. It returns a new array with result of visitor invokation for each original array element