# List of JavaScript Functions NOT supported by IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

I have been doing a lot JavaScript coding recently for front-end on IE8, and came across some issues that are caused by lacking of supporting functions from IE8.


**Here are some functions:**

(1) `indexOf()` [see discussion & solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1744310/how-to-fix-array-indexof-in-javascript-for-internet-explorer-browsers)
 (2) `base64()` [See source](https://code.google.com/p/stringencoders/source/browse/trunk/javascript/base64.js?r=210)
 (3) `String.trim()` [See discussion & solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308134/trim-in-javascript-not-working-in-ie)
 (4) `history.pushstate` [See discussion & solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6622449/emulate-polyfill-history-pushstate-in-ie)
 (5) `map()` [See discussion & solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7350912/is-the-javascript-map-function-supported-in-ie8) 
 (6) ArrayBuffer
 (7) bind
 (8) Create
 (9) DataView
 (10) every
 (11) filter
...

Please add more to this list if you came across any to help others.
Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure if this is something that's on topic here.

Comment: Just load this in and you'll have most ES5 functions in IE8: https://github.com/es-shims/es5-shim

Comment: Unfortunately this is off topic. It shouldn't be though, but SE's official policy is all good "reference" type questions have already been asked, so there shouldn't be any more.

Comment: Also, for a nice list of what works or not in IE 8 check out http://html5please.com/ and http://caniuse.com

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about generating a list resource, rather than asking a specific question.

Comment: There you go: https://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/, https://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/non-standard/

Comment: [JavaScript Version Information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s4esdbwz%28v=vs.94%29.aspx) at MSDN.

Comment: @FelixKling: Thanks for those 2 links.  I knew I had them in my bookmarks somewhere.

Comment: @FelixKling: There's also http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/es6/ ;)

Comment: @Rocket: Yep, but I figured it's not relevant for IE8 :D It will be very handy though once adoption increases. Very excited about it :)

Comment: @FelixKling: It's relevant to IE8 insomuch as nothing in it works in IE8! :D

Comment: @Rocket: Fair enough :D

Comment: [*ES5 Annex E*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-E) lists all the features that are incompatible with ed. 3. There are many more items than in the lists linked to in other comments (e.g. enumerability of arguments items that correlate to formal parameters).

Answer (score 0):

`Function.prototype.bind`

Like

```
setTimeout(function(){
  this.someFunc() //
}.bind(window));
```