# 0x800a01b6 - Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method

Tags: jquery, html, multi-select

I am using the Jquery multiselect for application checkbox dropdown.

I am getting issue in ie8 like
0x800a01b6 - Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method
But i am not getting any issue in ie9.please let me know how to resolve this?

my code:

```
 var Names = $("select").multiselect("getChecked").map(function () {
                  return this.value;
              }).get();



<select id="appNames" multiple="multiple">
 <option value='1'>app1</option>
 <option value='2'>app2</option>
 <option value='3'>app3</option>
 <option value='4'>app4</option>
 </select>
```

Please check this and let me know any suggestions

Comment: Try it this way and see what happens -> http://jsfiddle.net/nvW9h/

Comment: This thread should help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7350912/is-the-javascript-map-function-supported-in-ie8

Comment: What version of ie are you using?

Comment: ie9.i am checking ie8 based on f12.