# Map.set() polyfill for old IE?

Tags: javascript

Is there a `Map.set()` polyfill for <=IE11? I have found this, but i have no idea how it works. It's a little bit large: https://github.com/Riim/map-set-polyfill/blob/master/index.js

PS:

> Creating the new tag 'javascript-map' requires at least 1500
>   reputation. Try something from the existing tags list instead.

There remains only `javascript` left.

The full problem:
`Object.keys()` return a sorted array. That's not good in my case. `Map.keys()` return a unsorted array in filled order.

```
var map1 = new Map();
map1.set("123", "c");
map1.set(123, "b");
var iterator1 = map1.keys();
var myarray = [];
for (var i = 0; i < map1.size; i++) {
  myarray.push(iterator1.next().value);
}
console.log(myarray);
// Array ["123", 123]
```

But not all `Map.functions()` are available in IE. First `Map.keys()`. For this a polyfill for IE is available.  `Map.forEach()` is available from IE11, that's enougth.

```
var map1 = new Map();
map1.set(".", "z");
map1.set("2", "y");
map1.set(1, "x");
var mapkeys = [];
function getmyMapkeys(value, key, map) {
  mapkeys.push(key);
}
map1.forEach(getmyMapkeys);
console.log(mapkeys);
// Array [".", "2", 1]
```

The second is `Map.set()`, and for this i search a polyfill.

**Conclusion:** `new Map(iterator)` is not available in IE11. `Map.set()` is available from IE11 (11.0.9600.17843) (Win7 SP1). Another way to create a map and fill it with content does not exist.

Comment: 300 lines for two objects is too large? I've worked on source code with vastly more lines than that didn't do as much useful work...which does mean that the codebase wasn't very good but still. I don't think 300 lines is that bad. Especially after minification.

Comment: Im not sure what your problem is but it sounds like something easily fulfillable by a simple Javascript object populated as you need.  I use Map and Set a lot, but you can easily implement that functionality yourself with an object as it is able to do a K>V as easy as: `let obj = {}; obj[k] = v;`

Comment: Hm, i think... Read the Map with `Map.foreach()`. This can create a `var myarray = [[key, value],[key, value], ...]`. And than `.push()` the new entry/property in the array. Left create the Map new with `var map1 = new Map(myarray)`. ???

Comment: ... new Map(iterable) isn't available in IE11...

Answer (score 1):

For a 'budget' `Map` implementation with `get`/`set`, you can try using an object and its properties with `[]`:

```js
var realmap=new Map();
var budgetmap={};

realmap.set("a",1);
realmap.set("b",2);
realmap.set("a",3);
budgetmap["a"]=1;
budgetmap["b"]=2;
budgetmap["a"]=3;

console.log(realmap.get("a"));
console.log(budgetmap["a"]);
console.log(realmap.get("asd"));
console.log(budgetmap["asd"]);
```

The question certainly misses some detail(s), it is unlikely that you want to use `Map.set()` *only*.

---

If you need more functionality, that has to be programmed - there is a reason why those polyfills have grown that long.

Like a minimalistic one with string-only keys, providing `clear()`/`delete()`/`forEach()`/`get()`/`has()`/`keys()`/`set()`/`size`:

```js
function BudgetMap(init) {
  this.clear();
  if(init)
    for(var i=0;i<init.length;i++)
      this.set(init[i][0],init[i][1]);
}

BudgetMap.prototype.clear=function(){
  this._map={};
  this._keys=[];
  this.size=0;
};

BudgetMap.prototype.get=function(key){
  return this._map["map_"+key];
};

BudgetMap.prototype.set=function(key,value){
  this._map["map_"+key]=value;
  if(this._keys.indexOf(key)<0)this._keys.push(key);
  this.size=this._keys.length;
  return this;
};

BudgetMap.prototype.has=function(key){
  return this._keys.indexOf(key)>=0;
};

BudgetMap.prototype.delete=function(key){
  var idx=this._keys.indexOf(key);
  if(idx<0)
    return false;
  delete this._map["map_"+key];
  this._keys.splice(idx,1);
  this.size=this._keys.length;
  return true;
};

BudgetMap.prototype.keys=function(){
  return{
    _keys:this._keys,
    _idx:0,
    next:function(){
      if(this._idx<this._keys.length)
        return{value:this._keys[this._idx++],done:false};
      return{value:undefined,done:true};
    }
  };
};

BudgetMap.prototype.forEach=function(callback,thisArg){
  for(var i=0;i<this._keys.length;i++)
    callback.call(thisArg,this._map["map_"+this._keys[i]],this._keys[i],this);
};

// examples, copied from the links in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map#Browser_compatibility

// clear
var map1 = new BudgetMap();

map1.set('bar', 'baz');
map1.set('1', 'foo');

console.log(map1.size);
// expected output: 2

map1.clear();

console.log(map1.size);
// expected output: 0

// delete
var map1 = new BudgetMap();
map1.set('bar', 'foo');

console.log(map1.delete('bar'));
// expected result: true
// (true indicates successful removal)

console.log(map1.has('bar'));
// expected result: false

// forEach
function logMapElements(value, key, map) {
  console.log(`m[${key}] = ${value}`);
}

new BudgetMap([['foo', 3], ['bar', {}], ['baz', undefined]])
  .forEach(logMapElements);

// expected output: "m[foo] = 3"
// expected output: "m[bar] = [object Object]"
// expected output: "m[baz] = undefined"

// get
var map1 = new BudgetMap();
map1.set('bar', 'foo');

console.log(map1.get('bar'));
// expected output: "foo"

console.log(map1.get('baz'));
// expected output: undefined

// has
var map1 = new BudgetMap();
map1.set('bar', 'foo');

console.log(map1.has('bar'));
// expected output: true

console.log(map1.has('baz'));
// expected output: false

// keys
var map1 = new BudgetMap();

map1.set('0', 'foo');
map1.set('1', 'bar');

var iterator1 = map1.keys();

console.log(iterator1.next().value);
// expected output: 0

console.log(iterator1.next().value);
// expected output: 1
```

These methods really do the absolute minimum in order to reach their specs, there are only a few of them, and they total at ~50 lines already.

(I will try to test it with some IE, Microsoft offers virtual machine images exactly for this purpose at https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/ )

Comment: yes, not only. with `.get`, and this needs `.set`. budgetmap.get don't work.

Comment: I have expand the question with more details and code examples.

Comment: @Malama You would not say: `let a = '5';` `budgetmap.get(a)`, but instead:  `budgetmap[a]`

Comment: With Objects you have the problem with sort by `Object.keys()`. realized it. Read the topic.

Comment: @Malama: I suggest using an array for preserving insertion-order. I am on a mobile now, but will add some example implementation tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

From the code, it seems you will simply need to load the script ou your page, and then it will check if there if the `Map` and/or `Set` classes are missing from the global scope; if so, it creates the missing classes. Just load the script at the top of your page, and you should be good to go.

Comment: It's a little bit too large for me. Is there a smaller alternative available?

Comment: Well you could use the keys of a JS object as a set; see @tevemadar's solution.